# Finding cropped and scaled similar image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Given several large original images and a small image which is cropped and isotropic-scaled from one of large images, the task is to find where the small image comes from.

- cropping usually occur at the center of large image
- but exact crop boundary is unknown
- the size of small image is about 200x200
- again, exact size of small image is unknown
- if the size of cropped area is (width, height), the size of small image must be (width * k, height * k), where k < 1.0

[image: large image]   [image: small image]

I've read some related topics in SO and tried methods like ORB / color histograms, however the accuracy is not acceptable. Would you please give me some advice? Is there any efficient algorithm to deal with this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)?

Comment: Thanks. Since scale factor k and clip region is unknown,  it is infeasible to brute force all possible combinations for template matching. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The wording you are looking for is [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html), as you want to scan the original image and look for the origin of the cropped and scaled one.

The OpenCV tutorial has an extensive explaination for it