# Frame adjust - angle and zoom and scale - similar pictures cropped etc using openCv

Tags: python, opencv

If a user takes a series of pictures - and the scale/placement is off - can openCV be used to track-correct the frame of images? -- Adjusting each frame angle, zoom and scale - to crop all the pictures so the set doesnt jump -- like editing a video pan/zoom to smooth the video.

I found this example which is a good indicator of the concept - but could it scale, zoom/pan accurately? The problem is each image will be similar - but there would be changes so I am unsure how it would detect a reference image -- if it was possible to have -part of the image like the bottom act as a reference?

https://thinkinfi.com/image-alignment-and-registration-with-opencv/?utm_content=cmp-true
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
# Read Image to be aligned
imgTest = cv2.imread('input/test_form4.jpg')
# Reference Reference image or Ideal image
imgRef = cv2.imread('input/template_form.png')

# Convert to grayscale.
imgTest_grey = cv2.cvtColor(imgTest, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgRef_grey = cv2.cvtColor(imgRef, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
height, width = imgRef_grey.shape

# Configure ORB feature detector Algorithm with 1000 features.
orb_detector = cv2.ORB_create(1000)
 
# Extract key points and descriptors for both images
keyPoint1, des1 = orb_detector.detectAndCompute(imgTest_grey, None)
keyPoint2, des2 = orb_detector.detectAndCompute(imgRef_grey, None)
 
# Display keypoints for reference image in green color
imgKp_Ref = cv2.drawKeypoints(imgRef, keyPoint1, 0, (0,222,0), None)
imgKp_Ref = cv2.resize(imgKp_Ref, (width//2, height//2))
 
cv2.imshow('Key Points', imgKp_Ref)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Match features between two images using Brute Force matcher with Hamming distance
matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
 
# Match the two sets of descriptors.
matches = matcher.match(des1, des2)
 
# Sort matches on the basis of their Hamming distance.
matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance)
 
# Take the top 90 % matches forward.
matches = matches[:int(len(matches) * 0.9)]
no_of_matches = len(matches)
 
# Display only 100 best matches {good[:100}
imgMatch = cv2.drawMatches(imgTest, keyPoint2, imgRef, keyPoint1, matches[:100], None, flags = 2)
imgMatch = cv2.resize(imgMatch, (width//3, height//3))
 
cv2.imshow('Image Match', imgMatch)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# Define 2x2 empty matrices
p1 = np.zeros((no_of_matches, 2))
p2 = np.zeros((no_of_matches, 2))
 
# Storing values to the matrices
for i in range(len(matches)):
    p1[i, :] = keyPoint1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt
    p2[i, :] = keyPoint2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt
 
# Find the homography matrix.
homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC)

# Use homography matrix to transform the unaligned image wrt the reference image.
aligned_img = cv2.warpPerspective(imgTest, homography, (width, height))
# Resizing the image to display in our screen (optional)
aligned_img = cv2.resize(aligned_img, (width//3, height//3))
 
# Copy of input image
imgTest_cp = imgTest.copy()
imgTest_cp = cv2.resize(imgTest_cp, (width//3, height//3))
# Save the align image output.
# cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', aligned_img)
 
cv2.imshow('Input Image', imgTest_cp)
cv2.imshow('Output Image', aligned_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAhPmLXd0oM
https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/31/image-alignment-and-registration-with-opencv/
[Finding cropped and scaled similar image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078471/finding-cropped-and-scaled-similar-image)